# How to name REST API endpoints for very especific features?

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, endpoint, restful-url

So, I'm building a RESTful API, that's like a Parking system, it have ParkingLots and Cars that enter or leave ParkingLots, at this moment, my endpoints looks like this.

`POST '/parking-lots' // To create a ParkingLot`

`POST '/cars' // To create a Car`

But, how to name an endpoint that has EnterParkingLot or LeaveParkingLot feature following REST best pratices? I didn't found an article or blog post that answer this question so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, how to name an endpoint that has EnterParkingLot or LeaveParkingLot feature following REST best pratices? I didn't found an article or blog post that answer this question so far.

The key abstraction of information in REST is a [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1). Resources are generalizations of documents, not endpoints.

Useful work is a side effect of editing documents ([Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)).

If you are having trouble figuring out the URI, that probably means that you haven't been thinking enough about the documents (aka you don't yet have a clear understanding of your "resource model").

One idea that can sometimes help is to think about a client with cached documents.  When they send you one of these messages, which document in the cache is the most important one to [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4)?

In REST, it is normal (not necessarily common) to have a single resource handle many different kinds of edits.  For instance, we might submit an EnterParkingLot *form*, that would update a parking lot resource, and then later submit a LeaveParkingLot form that updates the *same* parking lot resource (with the code on the server parsing the requests to distinguish the different kinds of edits).

But it would also be fine to add a "parking ticket" resource to your resource model, with a different ticket tracking the arrival and departure of each car.

Domain experts are typically good at telling you what the documents are, and what names make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like:

```
POST '/parking-lot/$n/enter'
POST '/parking-lot/$n/leave'
```